# Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space with a certain property. Show that $X$ is regular.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space with the following property. For $a \in O \subset X$, where $O$ is open, there exists continuous $f: X \to [0,1]$ such that $f(a)=1, f(x)=0$ for $x \in X \setminus U$. Show that $X$ is regular.

As $X$ is Hausdorff we have to show that $X$ is $T_3$. I have the following characterization for a space to be $T_3$.

> A space $X$ is $T_3$ iff for all $x \in X$ and for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there exists neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V} \subset U$.

Can I use this here?

If I let $x \in X$ and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$, then $f(x)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for $y \in U^c$.

This map $f$ feels a bit like the characteristic map so should I somehow consider the boundary of $U$ here or what?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in X$ and let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$. We can assume that $U$ is open, so there is a continuous function $f : X \to [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 1$ and $f(y) = 0$ for all $y \in X \setminus U$. Now the important thing to use is that $f$ is continuous, and that preimages of open sets are open while preimages of closed sets are closed. For example, $V := f^{-1}(]\tfrac{1}{2},1])$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, and $W := f^{-1}([\tfrac{1}{2},1])$ is a closed neighbourhood of $x$. We have $x \in V \subseteq W \subseteq U$. Therefore, $\overline V \subseteq U$.